# What is Android 3DTourViewer?

Tags: applications

I'm removing or disabling all non-necessary apps since I had a malware scare this morning.  I'm using a Note 3 with Android Lollipop.

In the Application Manager "All" tab I see 3DTourViewer.  Can I disable this app without ill effect?

Comment: Please mention device and Android version in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Samsung bloatware not malware nor part of regular Android

It is safe to be disabled or removed, if your  device is rooted, as per this [reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2r44e8/apps_i_disabled_to_achieve_10_hours_sot_on_my/) post and this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/help/master-list-apps-safe-to-debloat-t2956860)

Comment: I don't have a rooted machine but I was able to remove this without ill effect.